# How to create an array of vectors

Tags: c++

How can I initialize an array of vectors properly ?

**Graph.h**

```
class Graph
{
public:
    Graph(int vertices); 
private:
    vector<int> adjacencyLists[];
}
```

**Graph.cpp**

```
Graph::Graph(int vertices)
{       
    adjacencyLists = new vector<int>[vertices];
}
```

Error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'std::vector<int>*' to 'std::vector<int> [0]'
 adjacencyLists = new vector<int>[vertices];
                ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perfect thing to you for your use case (a dynamically allocated array which can't change size after construction) is [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray). Sadly, this is currently not in the standard. Here's how it would work:

```
dynarray<vector<int>> adjacencyLists;

Graph::Graph(int vertices) : adjacencyLists{vertices} {}
```

Since it's not in the standard yet, I'd go with a `vector` (which is really a superset of `dynarray`, so its use is literally identical):

```
vector<vector<int>> adjacencyLists;

Graph::Graph(int vertices) : adjacencyLists{vertices} {}
```

Or if you really want to manage it all yourself, you could store it in a `unique_ptr`:

```
unique_ptr<vector<int>[]> adjacencyLists;
int numVertices;

Graph::Graph(int vertices)
    : adjacencyLists{new vector<int>[vertices]}
    , numVertices{vertices}
{}
```

With this approach you almost definitely want to store the size of `adjacencyLists` as well (as shown above), otherwise you won't be able to iterate through the array as you won't know how big it is.

No matter what you do, never have a raw pointer *own* memory. It should always be a `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` or some container. If you use the `delete` keyword, it's not modern c++.

Comment: I thought I would use array since the outter "vector" is of static size. So why not use array. Right ? However the question still stands. What was I supposed to do if I wanted an array of `MyRandomClass` ? If you look at the answer from @ColinBasnett thats a solution using pointers, but then my question is am I supposed to not use `[]` in a header file then ? I don't understand the conventions of c++, when it comes to arrays.

Comment: I think you mean the size never changes, but that's not quite the same as saying it's static. You accept it as an argument in runtime. In any case I'll update with more options...

Comment: Correct. Its an argument in runtime, never changes afterwards.

Comment: By that logic none should ever use arrays and only use vectors ?

Comment: @Shiro For dynamically allocated arrays? Ya, pretty much. For statically sized arrays (meaning, the size is known in compile time) use `std::array` instead.

Comment: @Shiro fwiw, the type you want (a std::vector that cannot change size through its lifetime) is proposed for the standard, but it's not in yet. It's called [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
vector<int> adjacencyLists[];
```

To:

```
vector<int>* adjacencyLists;
```

Comment: Is that a clear solution thought ? How is someone supposed to know that this is an array ? What are you supposed to do ? Never use arrays as a variable of a class ? and instead only use pointers ?

Comment: It's not clear, but it gets the job done without restructuring. Personally, I would use a vector of vectors (as @David pointed out). You could also ask the "how do you know it's an array" question about `const char*` variables.

Comment: What if I had an array of `MyRandomClass` ? What would I do then ? Either use the confusing pointer symbol, or use a `vector` instead of an array ? Doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Generally, since you're writing C++, you should be using C++ constructs, so I would go with vectors. Also note that if the array size is static, you can use std::array which had all the benefits of the nice vector-like interface and has a constant memory footprint.

Comment: I'd edit your answer and paste in that last comment, Colin. Dynamic Arrays aren't quite Global Thermonuclear War, but all the same the only correct move is not to play.

Comment: @ColinBasnett Can std:array initialize its length on run time ?

Comment: @Shiro No, the syntax is: `std::array<int, 8> values`. This is the memory allocation equivalent of `int values[8]`. The length *must* be known at compile-time.

Comment: @ColinBasnett Then the answer is no. Because run time is not compile time